# error with abs() in SurfaceView

Tags: android

I am calling abs(int) in a SurfaceView class and getting error msg that abs(int) is undefined for Preview - that is my SurfaceView class.   I've googled for this but without much success.   The hint system is not telling me an import is needed so I wonder if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abs()` is not defined in `SurfaceView`. Try `Math.abs(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to use the `java.lang.Math.abs(int value)` function? 
Or do you have a method with this name? 
It does not exist in SurfaceView, though.